# How To Insert 2 Values in 2 columns and rest null values in rest columns without using Create Table Statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, select

Please Check this **Sample Sql fiddle**:http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/f59ae.

In this way only i want output.first 2 columns Should contain values that can be anything
and rest columns should contain **Hello** values without considering **Create Table statement**.

I want to write a query that will insert 2 values into 2 columns and `Hello` into all other columns.

Suppose I have 100 columns then I want `10` and `20` values to be inserted into `col1` and `col2` and `Hello` into all other 98 columns.

Likewise if I have 200 columns then I want `10` and `20` values to be inserted into `col1` and `col2` and `Hello` into the other 198 columns.

I have written a query which but I thought it's a basic query so I am not writing here. So downvoters please consider that.

How to write this query???

Comment: please make an attempt.....

Comment: But i dont have idea thats why i didnt post my query.i have written query but thats a stupid one.so please remove your downvote if possible.

Comment: "But i dont have idea" - you can use a search engine, right?

Comment: This is a logical thing and google does not help in finding logical things

Comment: "This is a logical thing and google does not help in finding logical things" - erm, nope.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by just adding the `Default constraint` to column's which you don't want to insert values `explicitly`. I hope @Manish Pant's answer should help you to do that.

Based on your comments you want do this only by using query. So you need to use `Dynamic sql` to do this.

### Simple Demo

***Schema***

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Test](
    [id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Country] [varchar](100) NULL,
    [State] [varchar](100) NULL,
    [City] [varchar](100) NULL,
    [Population (in Millions)] [varchar](100) NULL
)
```

Declare a variable to hold the `Dynamic sql`

```
DECLARE @cl_val NVARCHAR(max)='Insert into Test('
```

Pull all the columns from `sys.columns` view and filter the identity column

```
SELECT @cl_val += Quotename(NAME) + ','
FROM   sys.columns
WHERE  Object_name(object_id) = 'Test'
       AND is_identity <> 1
ORDER  BY NAME

SELECT @cl_val = LEFT(@cl_val, Len(@cl_val)-1) + ') values (' -- Remove the trailing comma
```

Here add the values only to the `column` in `case statement` which you are explicitly passing value in `else` part add the `default value`

```
SELECT @cl_val += CASE 
                   WHEN NAME ='City' THEN '''A''' 
                   WHEN NAME='country' THEN '''c''' 
                   ELSE '''Hello''' 
                  END + ','
FROM   sys.columns
WHERE  Object_name(object_id) = 'Test'
       AND is_identity <> 1
ORDER  BY NAME

SELECT @cl_val = LEFT(@cl_val, Len(@cl_val)-1) + ')' -- Remove the trailing comma

--PRINT @cl_val 
EXEC Sp_executesql @cl_val 

select * from test
```

***Result***

```
id  Country State   City    Population (in Millions)
--  ------- -----   ----    ------------------------
1   c       Hello   A       Hello
```

Answer (score 0):

If All other columns are set as Nullable then into your Insert statement you can write statement By without considering your Nullable fields.

Suppose for example your Table named Student with properties is:

```
Student ::

Name,
RollNo,
OptionalField_1,
OptionalField_2,
OptionalField_3
```

where columns with `OptionalField` are Nullble fields.

In this case you can write your Query simply as ::

```
INSERT INTO Student (Name,RollNo) VALUES ('MyName',12);
```

So this will make an ENtry with two column values & all remaining as Nullable.

For your better understandings you can refer :: http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_insert.asp

Comment: Do you want to show 'Hello' if value of your column is 'NULL'?

In that case you case use normal 'case' statements of SQL

Comment: please See my Updated Question with sample Sql Fiddle

Answer (score 0):

You can use this for your query:

```
create table mytable(
                col1 varchar not null, 
                col2 varchar not null,
                col3 varchar not null default 'Hello',
                col4 varchar not null default 'Hello',
                col5 varchar not null default 'Hello',
                so on...... );
insert into mytable(col1,col2) values('10','20');
```

Comment: please See my Updated Question with sample Sql Fiddle

Comment: Please dont consider Insert Statement.i want to do this with sql query only